# What this particular file I am seeing in Ubuntu and why is it's taking up so much space?

Tags: linux, ubuntu, ubuntu-16.04

Why is `/dev/nvme0n1p3` taking up 70% on my system?

```
$ df
Filesystem     1K-blocks      Used Available Use% Mounted on
udev             4007080         0   4007080   0% /dev
tmpfs             805660     30136    775524   4% /run
/dev/nvme0n1p3 226022836 148770052  65748452  70% /
tmpfs            4028296     27220   4001076   1% /dev/shm
tmpfs               5120         4      5116   1% /run/lock
tmpfs            4028296         0   4028296   0% /sys/fs/cgroup
/dev/nvme0n1p1    610304     28700    581604   5% /boot/efi
tmpfs             805660        88    805572   1% /run/user/1001
```

I'm running [Glances](https://github.com/nicolargo/glances) on my laptop and it's saying warning or critical alerts (one entry). I'm assuming that's what it means.

```
2018-07-20 11:06:47       2018-07-20 10:56:03 (0:01:54) - WARNING on MEM (75.6)
```

I can take a screenshot of Glances too if anyone would like to look in more depth.

Comment: 'files' in `/dev/` are not "files" on your hdd/ssd, but rather 'file-like objects', most of which represent hardware on your machine. `/dev/nvme0n1p3` is a partition on an [NVMe](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/NVM_Express) SSD.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's not "taking up 70%"..

`/dev/nvme0n1p3` is your [NVME](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/NVM_Express) SSD which is mounted at `/` (the root filesystem) and is 70% full.

```
1K-blocks:   226022836 <- this is the total size of your disk (~220GB)
Used:        148770052 <- this is how many blocks are used (~148GB)
Available:   65748452  
Use%:        70%       <- this is the disk usage percentage
```

Answer (score 2):

You're reading the output wrong. That is the device that is mounted as `/` on the system. 70% of the space available to users on that device is used. Based on the device name I would venture to say that it's a partition of a PCIe SSD.